# How to remove previous element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.linkplus').next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

This works. But i do not understand why

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.linkplus').prev().remove();
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.linkplus').prev().remove();
    });
</script>
```

do not work. Is there a way to delete the previous element using javascript?

The previous element is:

```
<%= link_to '+', food_plans_path(abc: date),:method=> :post,:style=>"color:black;visibility:visible;float:right;font-weight:700;font-size:17px;",:class=>"linkplus"%>
```

I want to remove `linkplus` only when it comes before `linkx`

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding-top:7px;">
<%= week_calendar number_of_weeks: 4, events: @food_plans do |date, food_plans| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  <%= link_to '+', food_plans_path(abc: date),:method=> :post,:style=>"color:black;visibility:visible;float:right;font-weight:700;font-size:17px;",:class=>"linkplus"%>
  <% food_plans.each do |food_plan| %>
  <%if food_plan!=nil%>
  <%= link_to 'x', food_plan,:style=>"color:black;visibility:visible;float:right;font-weight:700;font-size:14px;",:class=>"linkx", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <%end%>
  <div >
  <!-- Displays proper collection select-->
  <%if food_plan.meal==nil%>
  <%=collection_select(:post, :food_plan_id, Meal.all, :name, :name, {prompt: '---'}, {:id=>"fsel", :onchange=>"window.location='#{meal_select_path(food_plan.id)}?meal=' + this.value"})%>
  <%else%>
  <%=collection_select(:post, :food_plan_id, Meal.all, :name, :name, {selected: food_plan.meal}, {:id=>"fsel", :onchange=>"window.location='#{meal_select_path(food_plan.id)}?meal=' + this.value"})%>
  <%end%>

  </div>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

upon inspect-element the ff show:

```
<a style="color:black;visibility:visible;float:right;font-weight:700;font-size:17px;" class="linkplus" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/food_plans?abc=2016-05-09">+</a>
<a style="color:black;visibility:visible;float:right;font-weight:700;font-size:14px;" class="linkx" data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/food_plans/7">x</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$('.linkplus')` has a previous element? Maybe you could add the html for this.

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the server-side code.

Comment: The code you posted WILL remove the previous element provided it has one. You can (and should) debug this by first running `console.log($('.linkplus').prev().length);`

Comment: Put a break point in there and try $('.linkplus').prev() in the console, see what it returns.

Comment: Hi I added the generated html

Comment: In your html, the first `<a>` tag is `linkplus`, so it has no previous element. So, `.prev().remove()` is doing nothing, as expected.

Comment: OH! haha thank you so much! I should have made it 'linkx'! It works now!

Comment: Your question was undeleted because by deleting it, you also deleted the answer I had given. Please accept the answer or comment on it if it did not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove `linkplus` only when it comes before `linkx`

The code you have shown deletes the element before or after the `linkplus` elements, not those elements themselves.

This is how to do what you ask in above quoted statement:

```
$('.linkx').prev('.linkplus').remove();
```

Comment: Could you indicate if this answered your question?